# How to turn off stack protector in linux kernel easily?

Tags: security, linux-kernel, compiling, configuration, kernel-modules

I wrote a simple module for the Linux Kernel and it has a stack buffer overflow vulnerability. I want to exploit the module, but I have to turn off the stack protector in the kernel first. How could I do this quickly and simply?

Is it required to compile the kernel every time?

Is there any other way to turn off stack protection in a module of the Linux Kernel (without compiling the kernel)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those options work by passing options to the compiler, so the most straightforward way is to recompile the kernel.

However for a reproducible and module-specific way kbuild allows you to set custom CFLAGs on a per-module basis.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt

You particularly want to set -fno-stack-protector for the modules you want to exploit.

DKMS additionally allows you to set up automatic rebuild for out of tree drivers against arbitrary kernel versions.